# How can I learn to include and link to libraries?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, linker, libraries

I'm trying to teach myself C++ programming. The C++ is the easy part. Some patience and good reference material goes a long way. Including and linking against libraries is the hard part. The instructions provided usually assume some knowledge which I don't have and don't know how to aquire without painfully slow trial and error.

The latest concrete example is http://cpp-netlib.org/

I've spent the whole afternoon trying to get it to work and I still don't even an idea why it's not working.

How can I learn this skill from the ground up?

Is it it normal to have such enormous difficulties learning how to do this?

Comment: Linking depends on the compiler and OS.

Comment: @Nick, I'd say more IDE (if used) than OS.

Comment: Yes and no...it really depends on what system you are using. Linux (with make files) tends to be the easiest (imho), CMake tends to be the hardest (on Windows at-least, on linux it is pretty slick), and the IDEs end up in between.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks on Windows. Does this explain why I'm finding this task overly difficult?

Comment: It is not normal (as you correctly guessed). But this is a reality you would have to face. It is easier on Windows than on Linux (if that may help).

Comment: @A.B., Go into the compiler and debugger settings, linker tab, and add the library name without any leading "lib" or extension (e.g. `mylibrary`). There should be tons of help available on the Wiki.

Comment: @chris True that, it seems he is using an IDE.

Comment: @SChepurin _' It is easier on Windows than on Linux'_ I'd doubt that! I felt just the opposite way, but may depend what you're using more often.

Comment: @A.B. _'I'm using CodeBlocks on **Windows**. Does this explain why I'm finding this task overly difficult?'_ I'd say yes to some extend. How did you install that `cpp-netlib` library?

Comment: @g-makulik - It certainly depends. But free commercial quality IDE+ well written and *well categorized* MSDN articles + MSDN Forums make learning curve slightly straighter for *most* of developers.

Comment: I download an official release, extracted it into a folder and then read the documentation. It needs the boost libraries so I installed those as well. Unfortunately some components of the boost library need to be built. I tried to build boost and somehow ended up with a 10 GB folder which took several hours to make, and I'm not sure how to go from there. So I included and link to just about everything in folder, add boost to environment variables, hoping that somehow it will work out, but I still get linker errors.

Comment: @SChepurin Sorry, that's simply rubbish! That kind of IDE support is exactly what causes the OP's alike questions, because it just hides some of the nitty critty details from the dumb user!

Comment: @A.B. You'll need to take care when installing boost, you're using the **same** toolchain as for your final project. `bjam` will lookup the MS compiler by default on windows systems. If you want MinGw, you'll need to start `bootstrap` from a MinGw shell.

Comment: @SChepurin _'well written and well categorized MSDN articles + MSDN Forums'_ Rarely seen such articles, can't tell you how many useless and unproductive hours I've been spending on searching for useful information on MSDN without any success (usually SO was more helpful at least).

Comment: @A.B. _'which took several hours to make'_ That sounds pretty suspect, which Windows platform & hardware you're using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the principle is pretty much always the same for any C++ compiler (the option flags mentioned are quite standard but might differ for particular compilers):

1. Install a library you want to use in your system (this may include a step to compile this library with your particular compiler toolchain).
2. Setup the include paths to be used for this library using the `-I` option
3. Use the headers of the library API in your code (`#include <libheader.h>`)
4. Setup the library paths to be used for this library using the `-L` option, tell the linker which libraries to link using `-l<extra>`, where extra should refer to some file named `lib<extra>.a` or `lib<extra>.lib`

Things to note:

1. Third party libraries might depend on further libraries you'd also need to install (compile with the same toolchain as your target uses)
2. On Windows using the MS Visual Studio (Express) toolchain you'll need to take care choosing the right library versions that are compliant with the 'threading model' and in general 'debug' / 'non-debug' library versions.

An (appropriate and useful) IDE will usually let you choose the toolchain (MinGW GCC, MS VS compiler, LLVM, etc.) on project setup, and offer some properties dialog to set these options.
What's necessary to setup for the toolchain, 3rd party libraries, IDE and OS you're using is a bit different learning curve and depends on what you want to use in particular.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The -I and -L option refers to what exactly? Is this something from a command line compiler?

Comment: @A.B. Yes, this refers to command line options. Usually you can specify this in your IDE per project options. I don't know how to do with Code Blocks in particular, since I've never used it. But you should able to find something like that in your project build options. **Note:** Your IDE (Code Blocks) just uses the command line compiler (toolchain) underneath, to build the project!